# AWS Query Filter Limits for

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using [Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Filter.html) do some searches via BOTO3 APIs. I don't see any documentation on limits for the filters like number of values we can provide in the `Values` attribute or the number `AND` conditions we can provide. I plan on using this `Filter` as part of `describe_instances` or `describe_volumes` API calls. Anyone have information on this?